# Stub performance.timing?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have written some code that extracts data from `performance.timing` to calculate page load times and returns the data in a `GET` request.

Is it possible to stub `performance.timing` to test the request against known data? If so, how?

Comment: It's JavaScript man, performance.timing = function () { return 0 };

Comment: @AdamH If only it were that easy! The browser seems to overwrite it with the original values.